# Handle Logrus and Cobra CLI in Golang

Tags: go, cobra, logrus

I am relatively new to the packages Cobra and Logrus in Golang and there is one little thing I would to ask for help when it comes to integrating them. I am working on a new Golang Cobra CLI which contains several commands/sub-commands. I'd like to use Logrus for logging inside my subcommands but I cannot find a good way to add new fields to the logger and pass them all to my subcommands.
This is what I have so far (I simplified my code for better explanation of my purpose):

```
├──pkg/
    ├──logger/
    |  ├──logger.go
├──cmd/
    ├── root.go
    ├──scmd/
    |  ├──scmd.go
```

```
// root.go

package cmd

func ExecuteRoot() {
    rootCmd := getRootCmd()
    err := rootCmd.Execute()
    if err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func getRootCmd() *cobra.Command {
    rootCmd := &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "mycli",
        PersistentPreRun: enableLogs,
    }

    rootCmd.AddCommand(scmd.Getscmd())

    return rootCmd
}


func enableLogs(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
    logger.ConfigureLogger(cmd.Flag("log-level").Value.String())
}
```

```
// logger.go
package logger

import (
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)


var MyCli *logrus.Entry


func ConfigureLogger(d string) {
    lv, err := logrus.ParseLevel(d)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatal(err)
    }
    logrus.SetLevel(lv)

    logrus.SetFormatter(&logrus.TextFormatter{
        DisableQuote: true,
        ForceColors:  true,
    })

    MyCli = logrus.WithFields(logrus.Fields{"foo1": "bar1", "foo2": "bar2"})
}
```

```
// scmd.go

package scmd

import (
   "pkg/logger"
   "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

func Getscmd() *cobra.Command {
    serviceUpdateCmd := &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "scmd",
        Run:   runServiceUpdateCmd,
    }

    return serviceUpdateCmd
}

func runServiceUpdateCmd(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
    logger.MyCli.Info("start scmd")
    
    // here what the command does ...
}
```

If I run it, I get what I am expecting: My subcommands (in this case `scmd`) logs at the level I set my flag `log-level` and the fields defined in my package `logger` are passed (`"foo1": "bar1"`, `"foo2": "bar2"`). However, I feel it is not the right way and could become problematic when creating unit test as I am using the global variable `var MyCli` from my `logger` package. Moreover, I should import it and use it as `logger.MyCli` in every Info, error, warn, etc line I want to log.

My question is whether there is a better approach to pass fields in Logrus on all subcommands I create or the way I explained above is my only option.

Any help or idea to improve my code is really welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out one of these articles: 1) https://le-gall.bzh/post/go/integrating-logrus-with-cobra/ and 2) https://droctothorpe.github.io/posts/2020/07/leveled-logs-with-cobra-and-logrus/

Comment: @jabbson That's actually part of what I am doing. I am also using Cobra's `PreRun` to initialize Logrus. However, they do not make use of `logrus.Entry` to include fields in the subcommand logs. I am not sure if there is a better approach to the one I am using above to pass those fields.

Comment: cobra commands allow passing `context` which you can initiate in `PreRun` and create the logger with `context.WithValue` and set the context in the command. From the subcommand, you can access the logger by extracting the logger from the context

Comment: other way is to pass logger to every command and subcommand from the main `Getscmd(logger)`